# Replacing apostrophe with preg_replace in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{$Image|regex_replace:"/(div class=+)/i":""}" />
```

I want to add apostrophes to this so I can replace them with nothing. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just do that on PHP side? P.S. god that smarty is ugly...

Comment: +1 for Briedis. I agree that using smarty to perform php operations is silly ... and I'm a Smarty apologist. Constrain your views to display logic.

Comment: I went ahead and put it all in my php. Figured out the code for doing it in php was a simple str_replace("'", '', $var);

Answer (score 1):

`{$Image|replace:"'":$var}`

Just incase your still wondering the smarty way to do it